# Generate Manager Report from Unit Tests (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, report, mspec

Is it possible to generate a report from Visual Studio 2008's integrated unit tests?  Say, one you hand off to an account manager to include in an invoice for the client.  One that looks say 10% as good as this?

[image]
<sub>(source: [skimedic.com](http://www.skimedic.com/blog/image.axd?picture=image_thumb.png))</sub>

I ask because [Rob Conery made a great video about using BDD](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/kona-3/) to develop applications.  And within it, he uses a 3rd party framework called Machine Specifications (or MSpec).  I have gotten MSpec working quite nicely on my end.  But, I do not want to introduce MSpec to the product team until this lifecycle is complete in about 6 months or so.

So, until then we are using Visual Studio's unit test.  But, I REALLY love the way Machine.Specification generates those very clean HTML reports.

Is there a way to generate such reports from the built-in Visual Studio 2008 unit tests?  Our bosses would love to hand off a report of our tests (in the 100s, 1000s).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you can run CruiseControl with MSTest and get a build report that includes test results.

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Using+CruiseControl.NET+with+MSTest

Comment: Nice option.  Using XSL to style the xml log.  Will investigate and get back to you.

Comment: I went ahead and added this as the answer for the bounty at this time.